# How to create a virtual cluster using docker on a single node?

Tags: docker, cluster-computing

I have one phisical Ubuntu 14.04 base node. Having 8 cores I want to create 4 (1 core) worker nodes and one head node (2 cores). It is not important for me that 1 core in docker worker will not be directly maped onto 1 hardware core.

Is it possible to create a "toy" cluster from a single node and which open source tools can simplify this porcess into some configuration file + 1-2 command lines?

Comment: The simple answer is yes. For an example take a look at how Solr can be run in a distributed manner on a single server node, using zookeeper and two instances of Solr: See https://hub.docker.com/_/solr/